# Calling ipinfo.io with promise and async (REACT)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I was wondering why I kept on getting `"GET https://ipinfo.io/ 429"` and

```
createError.js:17 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 429
    at createError (createError.js:17)
    at settle (settle.js:19)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:78)
```

Error. I was trying to figure it out how can i call the api of ipinfo.io using both promise and async wait via react.

I saw this jquery version that presented on the document but I am trying to use axios instead:

```
$.get("https://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
  console.log(response.ip, response.country);
}, "jsonp")
```

Here's how I called it using callback:

```
 componentDidMount() {
this.getData();
}

     getData() {
        axios.get("https://ipinfo.io", (response) => {
            console.log(response.ip, response.country);
        }, "jsonp");

    }
```

Here's how I called it via async await:

```
componentDidMount() {
this.getData();
}

async getData() {
    const response = await axios.get("https://ipinfo.io");
    console.log(response.ip);
}
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: 1. to get json, you need to request `https://ipinfo.io/json` (or you will load their homepage instead) 2. the API is meant for backends, which means with React being client-side, you'll get a CORS error

Comment: "If you exceed 1,000 requests in a 24 hour period we'll return a 429 HTTP status code to you"

Comment: ipinfo exposes Library for Middleware, which should be integrated in Middleware and expose as API which will be consumed by Front End React. https://ipinfo.io/developers

Comment: This works for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-kowalevski-g9vdr (but I guess xadm found the true cause)

Comment: This is interesting I haven't requested for around 1k requests yet but its still showing xhr.js:173 GET https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://ipinfo.io/json 429 (Too Many Requests)

Comment: {error: {title: "Rate limit exceeded",…}}
error: {title: "Rate limit exceeded",…}

Answer (score 2):

1. sign up for free at https://ipinfo.io/
2. get ipinfo ACCESS TOKEN
3. use it like so:

```
axios.get(`https://ipinfo.io/json?token=${ipinfo_token}`)
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data.ip);
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
  });
```